# Android - Set e Get Conversion

Tags: android

When trying to run the method "set" in the fields 'setRm,setCpf,setPermissao'  shows the error:

"The method setRm(Integer) in the type UsuarioVO is not applicable for the arguments (String)"

```
            UsuarioVO vo = new UsuarioVO();       

            vo.setRm(txtRm.getText().toString());
            vo.setCpf(txtCpf.getText().toString());
            vo.setCargo(txtCargo.getText().toString());
            vo.setCurso(txtCurso.getText().toString());
            vo.setSenha(txtSenha.getText().toString());
            vo.setPermissao(txtPermissao.getText().toString());
```

Here the code UsuarioVO:

package br.info.vo;

public class UsuarioVO {

```
private Integer rm;
private Integer cpf;
private String cargo;
private String curso;
private String senha;
private Integer permissao;

public Integer getRm() {
    return rm;
}

public void setRm(Integer rm) {
    this.rm = rm;

}

public Integer getCpf() {
    return cpf;
}

public void setCpf(Integer cpf) {
    this.cpf = cpf;
}

public String getCargo() {
    return cargo;
}

public void setCargo(String cargo) {
    this.cargo = cargo;
}

public String getCurso() {
    return curso;
}

public void setCurso(String curso) {
    this.curso = curso;
}

public String getSenha() {
    return senha;
}

public void setSenha(String senha) {
    this.senha = senha;
}

public Integer getPermissao() {
    return permissao;
}

public void setPermissao(Integer permissao) {
    this.permissao = permissao;
}
```

}

I believe the issue is to convert 'setRm', 'setCpf', 'setPemissao' that are of type integer to string, how to do this? somebody please?

Comment: Replace Integer.txtRm.getText().toString() by Integer.parseInt(txtRm.getText().toString()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse your String as an Integer:

```
vo.setRm(Integer.parseInt(txtRm.getText().toString()));
```